# Dual Monitor Setup with and HDMI TV

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a laptop and I would like to be able to use the laptop screen and my tv screen as a dual monitor setup. However every time I plug in my hdmi cable it shows up like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYrnW.jpg

I do not know what to do and some guidance would be great. Also if this helps my laptops resolution is 1366x768 and I would like to have the TV display run at 1080p.However if that is not possible then I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your TV doesn't support the resolution you are sending it.
go to your control center and open monitor settings.

Select a resolution for the TV, and press apply. Try different settings until you find one you are happy with.

Note: Some resolutions have multiple frequency settings. Changing the frequency can change the display.

Comment: My TV does support the resolution. It works without a problem on my windows machine.